# Uncountable union of positive sets being negative

Tags: measure-theory

Let $(X,\Sigma,\nu)$ be a signed measure space. A set $S \subseteq X$ is positive/negative  if for all subset $U \subseteq S, U \in \Sigma \rightarrow \nu(U) \geq 0$/$\nu(U) \leq 0$.

Is it true that an uncountable set of positive sets $(S_j)_{j \in M}$, where $|M| > |\mathbb{N}|$, may have a union that is negative?

I know that this is not possible when $M$ is countable, but is it possible to exhibit an example?

Comment: Not sure I really get the question, but wouldn't $[0,1]$ with negative Lebesgue measure work?  $\nu(\{x\})=0$, and thus $\nu(\{x\})\ge0$ for all $x\in [0,1]$, and yet $\nu([0,1])=-1$.

Comment: @ForgotALot Thanks. I fixed the wording to make it not so trivial.

Comment: ForgotALot's example still works.  For the question to be nontrivial, you want to require that your positive sets are "strictly positive", i.e. that $\nu(S)>0$.  But on the other hand, signed measures are often not allowed to be infinite, so it's impossible to have uncountably many disjoint strictly positive sets.  Are your signed measures allowed to be infinite?

Comment: @Eric Wofsey It is allowed to be infinite but cannot attain both of $\pm\infty$.

Comment: A set $S \subseteq X$ is called strictly positive if it is positive and for some $U_0 \subseteq S, U_0 \in \sum $ we have $\nu(U_0)>0$. If at least one from the sequence an uncountable set of positive sets  is strictly positive then  the  answer is no.

Comment: The answer for all diffused signed measure is yes.

Comment: It would be better the following  formulation: ''Is it true that an uncountable set of positive sets $(S_j)_{j\in M}$  where $|M|>|N|$, may have a union that is strictly negative?'' because for $S_j=\emptyset (J \in M)$ the answer is always yes, because $\emptyset$ sametimes is positive and negative, and hence  question in  its first formulation has no sense..

Answer (score 0):

In search of closure, here is an answer.  Yes, as the original poster has defined the problem, an uncountable set of positive sets $(S_j)_{j∈M}$ may have a union that is negative.  That is because a positive set $S_j$ is defined by the original poster as one with $\nu(U)\ge 0$ for all $U\subset S_j$, and thus a set $S_j$ with $\nu(U)=0$ for all $U\subset S_j$ qualifies as positive (and also as negative).

As noted a few days ago, an example is where $[0,1]$ is endowed with the negative of Lebesgue measure, and the positive sets are $\{x\}$ for $x\in [0,1]$. Not only is $\nu([0,1])\le 0$, as required by the original poster's definition of negative, but actually $\nu([0,1])=-1$.  Likewise for many subsets $U\subset [0,1]$ we have $\nu(U)<0$, while for others we have $\nu(U)=0$, for example the singletons $\{x\}$ and also, say, $\mathbb{Q}\cap [0,1]$.

On the other hand, suppose we redefine positive to mean that $\nu(S_j)>0$ and $\nu(U)\ge 0$ for all subsets $U$, and we redefine negative to mean $\nu(S_j)<0$ and $\nu(U)\le 0$ for all subsets $U$.  It's pretty obvious that we can't have an uncountable union of positives that's negative as described, simply because $S_j\subset \bigcup S_k$ and so, if $\bigcup S_k$ is negative as defined, we must have $\nu(S_j)\le 0$.

Comment: In your redefiinition you note $\nu(S_j)>0$.  You require in addition that $S_j \in \sum$, i.e. $S_j$ is measurable-This is not given in the question  given in the poster's  post. In general $S_j$ is not measurable.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the interval $[-1,1]$ together with the signed measure
$$\nu(U) = \begin{cases}
1 - \lambda(U) & 0 \in U\\
-\lambda(U) & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$
where $\lambda$ is the Lebesgue measure on $[-1,1]$. Now for each $x\in [-1,1]$ define $S_x = \{0,x\}$. Clearly for any $x$ this is a measurable set with measure $\nu(S_x)=1$. However, $\bigcup_{x\in\mathbb R}S_x = [-1,1]$, and $\nu([-1,1])=-1$.

Indeed, you can use any collection of Lebesgue null sets whose union is all of $[-1,1]$ for $S_x$, including such that $|S_x|>|\mathbb N|$ (which I suspect you *actually* wanted).

Answer (score -1):

The answer to the question
'Is it true that an uncountable set of positive sets $(S_j)_{j\in M}$  where $|M|>|N|$, may have a union that is strictly negative?''

is  no: Let $X=[-2,-1]\cup [1,2]$. Let $\nu_1$ be a counting measure in $[-2,-1]$ and let $\nu_2$ be - counting measure  in $[1,2]$.  We put $\sum=\{X +Y: X \in [-2,-1]~\&~Y [1,2]\}$. We put $\nu(X +Y)=\nu_1(X)+\nu_2(Y)$. The $\nu$ is signed measure. If $S_j$ is positive set then we have that $S_j \subset [-2,-1]$. Hence $\cup_{j \in M}S_j \subseteq [-2,-1]$. Since  $\cup_{j \in M}S_j$ does not contain any element of $[1,2]$ we  claim that it is not negative.

Comment: @Henry W   What you can say if $S_j=\emptyset$ for $j \in M$?  Then  under  your definition for an arbitrary signed measure,  $S_j$ is positive and same times  negative, as well $\cup_{j \in M}S_j$.  Hence you  question always  has  the positive answer.  By this reason I have utilized  your question. Why -1?

Comment: I did not put the $-1$.  However, it seems to me that you have not really given a proof.  What you need to prove is that for *no* measure space $X$ is there a set of subsets $S_j\subset X$ which is uncountable and positive whose union is negative.  You only prove that, in a particular example involving counting measure on two real intervals, one can't find such a set of subsets.  In addition, I don't see that your counting measure avoids one of $+\infty$ and $-\infty$ as required by a comment by the original poster.

Comment: @ForgotAlot  What set is $\emptyset$ -positive or negative?

Comment: @ForgotAlot  What if I take Lebesgue measure on [-2,-1] and negative counting measure in $[1,2]$?

Comment: In the original poster's definition "A set $S\subset X$ is positive/negative if for all subset $U \subseteq S, U \in \Sigma \rightarrow \nu(U) \geq 0/\nu(U) \leq 0$".  For $S=\emptyset$ this is a vacuous condition -- there are no subsets -- and therefore it would seem that the empty set is both positive and negative.  Alternatively you could say that $\emptyset\subset\emptyset$ in which case the same conclusion holds because $\nu(\emptyset)=0$. I should add that I take the definition of "positive" and "negative" in this sense from the original poster's posting; I have never seen it in a book.

Comment: I am not sure what you're asking re using Lebesgue measure rather than counting measure on $[-2,-1]$, except I note that it does avoid $+\infty$; not avoiding it was a problem with your answer example.

Comment: I did not give the -1.

Comment: @ForgotAlot  Sorry that  you have no answered on my second question.